# JQuery: Toggle two radio buttons by clicking on only one of it

Tags: jquery

**How can I toggle the checked status of two radio buttons by clicking on only one of them?**

Please take a look at the example below.

```css
.option{
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;     
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  user-select: none;    
}

.option-checkbox-1{
  opacity: 0.7;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="option option-checkbox-1">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="group[1]" value="1" checked="checked">
Radio 1
</label>
<label class="option option-checkbox-2">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="group[1]" value="2">
Radio 2
</label>
```

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by toggle here?

Comment: Isn't this what radio buttons do by default...?

Comment: Also note that despite `pointer-events: none` I can still select the first radio with the keyboard, if you're attempting to stop user selection

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you can clicked the `checked` radio button and it becomes unchecked, while the other becomes `checked`.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: You should use checkboxes in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue to overcome in this setup is that each radio button has a default true/false behaviour in the browser which fires even before any jQuery / javascript event listener fires.

The way to get around this is to toggle a `class` backwards and forwards and then update the state of the radio button by only ever referring to the `class`.

Here's this straightforward approach using jQuery and native javascript:

**jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('checked');
          $(this).hasClass('checked') ? $(this).prop('checked', true) : $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input type="radio" class="checked" checked /> Radio A
<input type="radio" /> Radio B
</form>
```

---

**Javascript:**

```js
var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

function toggleCheck() {
    radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton){
        radioButton.classList.toggle('checked');
        radioButton.classList.contains('checked') ? radioButton.checked = true : radioButton.checked = false;
    });
}

radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton){
    radioButton.addEventListener('click',toggleCheck,false);
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" class="checked" checked /> Radio A
<input type="radio" /> Radio B
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Remove "pointer-events: none;"

```
.option-checkbox-1{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```